# How to push empty file to github?

Tags: angularjs, github

I have angular project, which I need to push on github. However, it contains a lot of component folders with empty files in each.I need the way how to push that project on the github because common drag&drop throws error.

Comment: Do you know how to work with Git? (Not github, git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to go throw the basic git tutorial

here is an amazing doc for beginners

https://guides.github.com/introduction/git-handbook/